# Ember CLI tests fails inside dev container

Tags: testing, ember.js, ember-qunit, testem

I'm working in a VSCode Dev Container on Debian Release 10. I'm able to run `CI=true ember test` in my own terminal without fail but running it in my container instance throws;

```
not ok 1 Chrome - [undefined ms] - error
    ---
        message: >
            Error: Browser exited unexpectedly
            Non-zero exit code: null
            Stderr: 
             qemu: uncaught target signal 5 (Trace/breakpoint trap) - core dumped
            qemu: uncaught target signal 5 (Trace/breakpoint trap) - core dumped
            [0719/094328.695395:ERROR:bus.cc(393)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
            [0719/094328.705723:ERROR:file_path_watcher_linux.cc(326)] inotify_init() failed: Function not implemented (38)
            [0719/094328.826667:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(996)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=1002
            [0719/094328.827080:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1316)] The GPU process has crashed 1 time(s)
            
            DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:38109/devtools/browser/fe31b478-52ab-4169-aa4a-9263c3f2a29f
            qemu: unknown option 'type=utility'
            [0719/094328.888291:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(996)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=1002
            [0719/094328.888371:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1316)] The GPU process has crashed 2 time(s)
            [0719/094329.022382:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(996)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=1002
            [0719/094329.022475:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1316)] The GPU process has crashed 3 time(s)
            [0719/094329.022628:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(415)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.
            qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
            
            
        browser log: |
            {"type":"error","text":"Error: Browser exited unexpectedly"}
            {"type":"error","text":"Non-zero exit code: null"}
            {"type":"error","text":"qemu: uncaught target signal 5 (Trace/breakpoint trap) - core dumped\nqemu: uncaught target signal 5 (Trace/breakpoint trap) - core dumped\n[0719/094328.695395:ERROR:bus.cc(393)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory\n[0719/094328.705723:ERROR:file_path_watcher_linux.cc(326)] inotify_init() failed: Function not implemented (38)\n[0719/094328.826667:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(996)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=1002\n[0719/094328.827080:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1316)] The GPU process has crashed 1 time(s)\n\nDevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:38109/devtools/browser/fe31b478-52ab-4169-aa4a-9263c3f2a29f\nqemu: unknown option 'type=utility'\n[0719/094328.888291:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(996)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=1002\n[0719/094328.888371:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1316)] The GPU process has crashed 2 time(s)\n[0719/094329.022382:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(996)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=1002\n[0719/094329.022475:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1316)] The GPU process has crashed 3 time(s)\n[0719/094329.022628:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(415)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.\nqemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped\n"}
```

I'm using these arguments in my testem

```
ci: [
        // --no-sandbox is needed when running Chrome inside a container
        process.env.CI ? '--no-sandbox' : null,
        '--headless',
        '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
        '--disable-software-rasterizer',
        '--mute-audio',
        '--remote-debugging-port=0',
        '--window-size=1440,900',
      ]
```

This is my versioning setup

```
npm -v && yarn -v && node -v && ember -v
6.14.13
1.22.5
v12.22.3
ember-cli: 3.26.1
node: 12.22.3
os: linux x64
```

Comment: Does your container have access to your gpu for hardware acceleration? If not, you can try the adding the --disable-gpu flag to your testem.

Comment: @Gaurav yeah the usage of --disable-cpu changes nothing unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed by creating a new Dockerfile, the official node docker image instead of the Microsoft provided DevContainer one [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/node) and installing all required dependencies for headless Chrome [here](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#chrome-headless-doesnt-launch-on-unix)